# AWS API Gateway with external authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I've built a backend which distributed on several EC2 instances (microservice architecture) and I'm using AWS API Gateway to channel all the requests through a single endpoint. I also built a token-based request authentication system, which requires that every request validates a token on the Auth Service before it is completed.

Is there anyway to tell API Gateway to do the verification by calling the Auth Service itself, rather than having to implement it myself on every endpoint of the backend?

Comment: Can you mark this as the accepted answer so that others can find it more easily please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Api Gateway team here.

Thanks for your feedback. We have this item on our roadmap and we'll definitely work on addressing it. For now, you'll have to implement it outside Api Gateway.

EDIT 2/17

We've now launched custom authorizers, a new feature that adds a Lambda-based auth layer on your API Gateway RestApi.

Blog post - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/
Docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html